# Grouping by when id can be in column 1 or 2

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

On my website, members can send messages to each other.
Here is my Message class :

```
public partial class Message
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateMsg { get; set; }
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    public string ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to do a query that get the last message for each opened discussion. Since I have no "discussion id", I can't do "group by discussionId" and then select the first one in each group.
How could I do ?

```
public IEnumerable<Message> Get_DiscussionsFor(string userId)
        {
            List<Message> list;
            using (var context = new ModelContainer())
            {
                IQueryable<Message> dbQuery = context.Set<Message>();               

                list = dbQuery
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(m => m.SenderId.Equals(userId) || m.ReceiverId.Equals(userId))
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m.DateMsg)                        
                    .ToList<Message>();
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: From this structure I don't see how you would link two messages at all.  You can't just link by sender/receiver because they could be separate discussions or threads.

Comment: How do you even know what discussion a message falls into?

Comment: I assume that a discussion thread is all messages between user1 and user2 : messages with ((user1 as sender && user2 as receiver) || (user2 as sender && user1 as receiver)).

Answer (score 2):

Well, this might work, although it won't be fast.

Here's the first part of your query:

```
            var list1 = dbQuery
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(m => m.SenderId.Equals(userId) || m.ReceiverId.Equals(userId));
```

I am going to create another query, that creates an anonymous type encapsulating the message and the ID of the other user.

```
            var senderFirst = list1
                .Where(m => m.SenderId.Equals(userId))
                .Select(
                 m => {
                   Message = m,
                   OtherUser = m.ReceiverId
                 });
```

I'm creating another one, this time for the ones where the user we want is the receiver, and the Other User is the Sender:

```
          var receiverFirst = list1
              .Where(m => m.ReceiverId.Equals(userId))
              .Select(
                m => {
                   Message = m,
                   OtherUser = m.SenderId,
                });
```

I am now concatenating them. I can do this because they have exactly the same properties with the same types and same names: behind the scenes, they're the same anonymous type.

```
            var list2 = senderFirst.Concat(receiverFirst);
```

As a result, each message involving the user you want will appear with the other user identified as `OtherUser`.  Note that we haven't changed the `Message` object at all: it's still there, with the right values for `SenderId` and `ReceiverId`.  We just wrapped it in another object, with additional metadata.

You said that any message involving a given two users is in the same discussion.  So, we can now simulate grouping by discussion by grouping by the `OtherUser`:

```
             var list3 = list2.GroupBy(m => m.OtherUser);
```

So now we have grouped messages.  You can now sort each group and select the final message.

```
             var list4 = list3
                 .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Message.DateMsg).First());
```

And now you have your `List<Message>`, because your `Message` object is still in there, ready to be sprung from encapsulation:

```
             var list = list4
                 .Select(m => m.Message)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a little complicated but that might work. Also I may have to change my messaging system design in order to make it simpler :-s